# Visible Artifacts Compositing two UIImages with UIGraphicsContext using Hard Light transfer mode

Tags: ios, composite, uigraphicscontext

I am compositing two UIImages together using a UIGraphicsContext.

It works for the most part, but using the Hard Light CGBlendMode, I am getting strange artifacts that are not present if I use a Hard Light transfer mode in Photoshop.

I would try to use Core Image, but I need to be able to control the opacity of the top layer being transferred with Hard Light, and as far as I can tell that is not possible.

Here is the image created with a UIGraphicsContext:
[image]

Here it is using the same layers and opacity in Photoshop:
[image]

Here is the base image:
[image]

And the layer being composited with 60% opacity using Hard Light:
[image]

I have tried setting the context interpolation quality to high, using a transparency layer, but nothing has made any improvement.

My code is below. Does anyone know how to fix this, or alternative ways of achieving the same results that I am getting in Photoshop?

```
public extension UIImage {

    public func compImagesWithImage(_ topImg: UIImage, blendMode: CGBlendMode, opacity: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

        let baseImg = self

        if let cgImage = baseImg.cgImage {
            let baseW = CGFloat(baseImg.cgImage!.width as size_t)
            let baseH = CGFloat(baseImg.cgImage!.height as size_t)

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: baseW, height: baseH))
            if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
                context.saveGState();
                context.interpolationQuality = .high

                let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: baseH)
                context.concatenate(flipVertical)

                context.setAlpha(1.0)
                context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
                context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(baseW), height: CGFloat(baseH))))

                context.setAlpha(opacity)
                context.setBlendMode(blendMode)
                context.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)

                context.draw(topImg.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(baseW), height: CGFloat(baseH))))

                context.endTransparencyLayer()

                context.restoreGState();

                let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                return finalImage

            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it: [Higlight Artifacts When Using Hard Light Blend Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511272/higlight-artifacts-when-using-hard-light-blend-mode?rq=1)

I just had to set the alpha of the base layer to 0.99.

Here is the updated code:

```
public func compImagesWithImage(_ topImg: UIImage, blendMode: CGBlendMode, opacity: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {

    let baseImg = self

    if let cgImage = baseImg.cgImage {
        let baseW = CGFloat(baseImg.cgImage!.width as size_t)
        let baseH = CGFloat(baseImg.cgImage!.height as size_t)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: baseW, height: baseH))
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            context.saveGState();
            context.interpolationQuality = .high

            let flipVertical = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: baseH)
            context.concatenate(flipVertical)

            context.setAlpha(0.99)
            context.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal)
            context.draw(cgImage, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(baseW), height: CGFloat(baseH))))

            context.setAlpha(opacity)
            context.setBlendMode(blendMode)
            context.beginTransparencyLayer(auxiliaryInfo: nil)

            context.draw(topImg.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(baseW), height: CGFloat(baseH))))

            context.endTransparencyLayer()

            context.restoreGState();

            let finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

            return finalImage

        }
    }
```